# Why does the VS2015 Typescript sample project include content files?

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-2015

I have created two different kinds of sample projects using VS2015.  The web application (using Typescript) and the Typescript application.

Both work but the web application has a lot of overhead as it seems to include many .net dlls.  The Typescript application is a lot simpler.

However, when I look at the project files for the two I notice that the typescript application project file has many Content Includes for each of the files, while the other is a very minimal size project file.

Can someone explain why this is?

Comment: Read this: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb629388.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They're fundamentally different. Compiling a web application generates a .NET assemblies for which dependencies are managed by .NET framework, hence the presence of DLL dependencies. Compiling a TypeScript project generates js files. .NET framework isn't involved to manage your dependencies.